# SQL error "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function"

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm getting sql error

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

and it appears to come from returned values that are 14 characters in length.

The our outstanding share values for securities that we get from a feed.  For instance, a value such as `195461597.62 M` we're trimming off the `.62 M` and multiplying by 1000, but the values with 14 or more characters returns the *Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function* error, but if I remove one character from value it runs fine.

This field is set for a `DATA_LENGTH` of 100 and the front end application where value displays is set for 30 characters, so not sure what errors is telling me.

Here's my SQL:

```
select udf_char15, (convert(int,(substring(ltrim(rtrim(UDF_CHAR15)),0,len(UDF_CHAR15) - 5)))*1000)
from CSM_SECURITY_CUST
Where UDF_CHAR15 is not null
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Pass 1 to substring not 0

Answer (score 0):

You could use the position of the decimal to make it length agnostic;

```
select cast(left(UDF_CHAR15, charindex('.', UDF_CHAR15) - 1) as int)
```

Comment: I don't think the decimal is the problem, but the total length.  Since all data retrieved ends with .XX M we are trimming the last 5 characters including the decimal.  The error occurs only when there are 9 or more remaining characters.